# How to make text fall under image when windows is resized

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get my text to fall under the image when the window is resized, I am new to coding and this is the very first thing ive tried to code so dont judge lol.
`Code`https://jsfiddle.net/b17nhj3y/1/#&togetherjs=wdEDSQBkB2

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, preferably as a [MCVE]. It is easier for us to help you if we don't have to go off site to find your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in CSS, if you want to display elements in a page differently on different devices/screen size.

Sample:

```
@media (max-width: 12450px) { your style here.. }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **media queries** to make your webpage responsive :

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 720px) {
  #p {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 500%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #757575;
    transform:translateX(-0.5%);
  }
}
```

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/gs86uL5k/

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot of negative margins and absolute positions.  Try this for the CSS.

```
#p {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 25px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #757575;
  transform: translateX(-0.5%);
}
```

If you need this to only happen on a certain screen size, check out media queries.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Hey, the top is how it looks when the page is fully expanded, closing in I was trying to make the photo smaller and go above the the header and paragraph https://imgur.com/a/Dbltv6m